# Install audacity with command line. No root access

Tags: audio, command-line, root, apt-get, audacity

Is there an easy way to install audacity from the command line with no root access ?

I don't have either apt-get:

```
apt-get: command not found
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Basically, I am looking for an audio player, with a play bar, and in which I can see the signal and zoom in and out.

Comment: @Lucky. Do you mean why?

Comment: no, I meant is it Ubuntu or Slackware, RPM or something else?

Comment: @Lucky. It seems to be Scientific Linux

Comment: try yum install or sudo yum install

Comment: @Lucky. Thank you. yum seems broken. "There was a problem importing one of the Python modules." I'll try to fix it.